# How can i run my java program for multiple inputs at a time in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, ide

Suppose I have a java program in eclipse. I want to run the program for multiple test cases I provided simultaneously instead of checking each input individually.(Like test cases checking in leetcode ,CodeChef or cph extension in vscode). How can I set this in eclipse?

here is an example of cph in vscode
[image]

I want to do the same for the eclipse.

I would appreciate any effort for answering the question :)

Comment: At scale this is usually done using unit testing frameworks. While you could instead create your Java Application launcher in the Launch Configuration dialog (if you've ever run your application before, it already has one), open the dialog from the "Run"->"Run Configurations..." menu action, select and Duplicate that launch configuration via the dialog's toolbar, change the inputs/arguments as needed, and then create a Launch Group and add the other launchers into it, this doesn't resemble a real use case all that much in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code with the following in main:

```java
t = read in number of test cases
while(t-- > 0) {
  //your solution here
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort . But is there any alternative without editing the code